# Неопределённое поведение при передаче данных через сокеты

Tags: java, сокет

При передаче данных через сокеты всё работает нормально, но в какой-то момент ломается, например:

Сервер постоянно посылает клиенту пакет **с кодом 37** (Обновление позиции объекта в игровом мире), и **длиной data в 30 байт**, через какое-то время (обычно с сервером соединены **2 клиента**) внезапно какой-то клиент читает пакет с **кодом 30 (такого не определено)** и **длиной data в 0 байт**. 
Рано или поздно, но так происходит со всеми клиентами.

Возможно это у меня проблемы с внимательностью, но я несколько раз проверял методы `write` и `read`. Больше нигде в проекте нет чтения/записи через сокеты.

**С кодом 37 data != null**

Класс Packet:

```
private final Code code;
private final byte[] data;

private Packet(Code code, byte[] data){
    assert code != null;
    this.code = code;
    this.data = data;
}

public void write(DataOutputStream output) throws IOException {
    int size;
    if (data == null){
        size = -code.code-1;
    }
    else {
        size = data.length;
    }
    output.writeInt(size);

    if (data != null) {
        //System.out.println(code.code); -> 37
        output.write(code.code);
        output.write(data);
    }
}

public static Packet read(DataInputStream input) throws IOException {
    int code;
    byte[] data;

    int size = input.readInt();

    if (size < 0){
        code = -size-1;
        return valueOf(Protocol.get(code));
    }
    code = input.readUnsignedByte();

    data = new byte[size];
    input.readFully(data);

    return valueOf(Protocol.get(code)/*берем Code из массива*/, data);
}
```

Класс Code:

```
public class Code {
    public final int code; // находится в пределах [0:255]
    public final String name;

    Code(String name, int code){
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось совсем неожиданно, но объяснимо. Проблема была в отсутствии синхронизации методов отправки пакетов, в итоге была возможна одновременная запись в `DataOutputStream` двух пакетов, что приводило к каше данных и трудноуловимому багу, на поиск которого я потратил много часов и нервов. Помогло добавление `synchronized` блока. Надеюсь этот ответ будет полезен тем, кто столкнется с такой-же проблемой.